# How to divide features for co-training semi supervied SVM in matlab?

Tags: matlab, classification, svm

I want to use co-training of self labeled SSC.My base classifier is support vector machine.please help me for writing co-training algorithm with matlab.

Comment: What did you do till now? Normally for getting some help here, you'd better share what you have done, and others will help you to get it fixed, and find out where the problem is. I am seeing some references on a co-training algorithm on Matlab like this: https://github.com/kemalty/DemocraticCoLearning/blob/master/democraticCo_train.m all you need is to do some modifications

Comment: I'm going to write TSVM algorithm by co-training.Labeling is done by two classifiers(svm).Each classifier will give its labeled data to the other classifier.My problem is choosing two feature sets for each classifier that each set independently work well

Comment: Feature Selection method only selects a good set hence the other features are not good compared to the selected set,i want to choose two good feature sets

Comment: I have some old experience in using Co-training, also using TSVM. But in my understanding, co-training comes handy when you have multimodal features or at least two independent sets of features.  One good example is when you have text and image features for a given document. Then you can use Co-training or multi-view learning where each learner ( classifier in your case) is done on a subset of the features and help other classifiers to make the final decision.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .can you give me your code?

Comment: Sorry, I have just got back to this now. I am afraid I do not have my codes anymore. But if you have done something, feel free to share in this post, or another post. I will be more than happy to hep.